# EC2 pricing for multiple stop-start within the same hour

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, start

In http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html, it says,

> Each time you start a stopped instance we charge a full instance hour, even if you make this transition multiple times within a single hour.

Does this mean if within the same hour, I stopped-start my instance for 5x, I will be charged for 5 hours?

Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what it says!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start an EC2 instance, you are immediately charged for 1 full hour. So if you start and stop an instance 5 times in 20 minutes then you will be charged for 5 hours.